# how build my own package at last time of build rootfs by buildroot?

Tags: package, external, buildroot

i create br2_external packages and want begin build them only if rootfs is already built.
May be possible set depencies in root mk-file of my external package tree? but unknown who is the last... or is posible more correc solution?

Answer (score 0):

Buildroot does not support building packages after the rootfs has been build using the normal package infrastructure. The order is fixed to the following (somewhat simplified):

1. Build all packages
2. Run the target finalization scripts (including the post-build script).
3. Build the rootfs images.
4. Run the post-image script.

There is one exception to this. For the kernel-with-builtin-initramfs (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_INITRAMFS), there is an extra `make` rule in the linux package to rebuild linux after the rootfs cpio image has been built. It is possible to do something similar in a BR2_EXTERNAL package.

Usually, however, you don't actually need to really build anything after the rootfs has been generated; instead, you just need to run some post-processing tool. Therefore, the usual approach is to build that post-processing tool as a normal package, and run it from a post-image script.

It is also possible to write a package so it doesn't do anything in the build and install steps, and run something like `make -C "$(make printvars VARS=MY_PACKAGE_BUILD_DIR)"` from the post-image script.